# Is there a way to modify the default camera position in the world file?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would like to move the camera position to something other than what it defaults to.  How would I go about this in the world file?  There is some documentation but it is vague.

Here is the code I am using changing the camera pose does nothing.  I needed to put a name in for the camera, because it would not parse otherwise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.3">
    <world name="default">
   <gui>
      <camera name="user_default">
            <pose>-1 0 -2 0 -5 0</pose>
      </camera>
    </gui>    
<scene>
<shadows>false</shadows>
</scene>    


        <include>
            <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
        </include>
        <include>
            <uri>model://sun</uri>
        </include>
        <include>
            <uri>model://robopede</uri>
        <name>robot</name>
            <pose>-2.5 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        </include>
        <include>
            <uri>model://wall</uri>
            <name>wall_0</name>
            <pose>-3 0.22 0 0 0 0</pose>
        </include>
    <include>
            <uri>model://wall</uri>
            <name>wall_1</name>
            <pose>-3 -0.22 0 0 0 0</pose>
        </include>
               <include>
            <uri>model://wall</uri>
            <name>wall_2</name>
            <pose>-2 0.22 0 0 0 .5</pose>
        </include>
    <include>
            <uri>model://wall</uri>
            <name>wall_4</name>
            <pose>-2 -0.22 0 0 0 .5</pose>
        </include>

    </world>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/408/is-there-a-way-to-modify-the-default-camera-position-in-the-world-file?/) by [mdedonato](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/86/mdedonato/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mdedonato](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/86/mdedonato/) on 2012-12-07**:
This is very annoying in the new gazebo.  Can someone post their code to move the camera?  I tried the   setting, but i cannot get it to work.  I am most likely doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

```
<sdf version='1.3'>
  <world>
    <gui>
      <camera>
        <pose>my custom pose as a six-tuple(x,y,z,roll,pitch,yaw)</pose>
      </camera>
    </gui>    

  </world>
</sdf>
```

---

Originally posted by [natepak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/57/natepak/) with karma: 111 on 2012-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2015-05-02**:
Is this documented anywhere? [sdformat.org](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=world#camera_pose) lists nothing. What is the default orientation that roll/pitch/yaw effects?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-05-03**:
I couldn't find it documented, but the pose is described with respect to the world. 0 0 0 0 0 0 is centered at world origin looking towards the positive X axis with Z up and Y to the left. Note that the initial camera pose is not zero.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-05-04**:
[Documentation](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=world#world_gui)

**Comment by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on 2015-06-20**:
With SDF1.4, data format is as what @chapulina mentions. I think `tuple` (that can be commonly embraced in parenthesis) stated in the answer might be a bit confusing.

**Comment by [okan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2527/okan/) on 2018-06-30**:
I do not know when that changed, but camera tag needs to have name attribute otherwise SDF parse gives error. It should be like  ..

Also it would be beneficial to mention that the pose x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw will be separated from each other with space not comma. Another trick to set an appropriate camera position would be moving the camera by running the simulation and getting required pose by selecting the GUI on the model explorer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The answer provided by @natepak answers it. Just a few minor modifications and clarifications if you are using Gazebo 9+. **My low karma does not allow me to make edits, so posting a separate answer here**:

1. The element `camera` requires a `name` attribute. It is `'user_camera'` for the Gazebo view camera.
2. The angles should be in radians
3. Elements in `pose` should be separated by space. `<pose>x y z roll pitch yaw</pose>`

Example:

> ```
> <world>
>     <gui>
>         <camera name="user_camera">
>             <pose>-7.35 -3.59 39.73 0 1.417 0.124</pose>
>         </camera>
>     </gui>
> </world>
> ```

---

Originally posted by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6243/subodh-malgonde/) with karma: 31 on 2018-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-08-15**:
For me on Gazebo 7 it works with camera name  `gzclient_camera`.

**Comment by [desmond13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8998/desmond13/) on 2020-12-01**:
For me this is the most complete answer, thanks! I cannot vote it up since I don't have enough karma.